# How to generate a postfix notation from code segment?

Tags: compiler-construction, intermediate-code

please can anyone explain with out the use of any programming language tool, what is the rule for converting a code segment,(not an expression) to postfix notation....Thank you I appreciate in advance of your responses

Comment: What do you mean by postfix notation if you're not talking about expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Intermediate Code, and Final Code uses prefixed notation, not posfixed Notation.

Example (Prefixed Notation) :

```
Sum B, Mem[6455];
```

Example (Posfixed Notation) :

```
B, Mem[6455], Sum
```

Let's suppose you mean "prefixed notation".

There are two groups of instructions that can be converted into a prefixed notation.

The first are expressions like:

```
somevar <- (x + y);
```

Second, non return functions also know as "procedures" or "subroutines".

```
GotoXY(Column, Row);
```

In  the second, the I'd of the function becomes the prefixed Id. of the instruction, followed by the parameters.

```
GotoXY Column, Row
```

Usually the Id. Indicates an address:

```
Load RegisterA, Column;
Load RegisterB, Row;
Load RegisterC, GotoXY
Call RegisterC
```

This may differ from one intermediate code to another.

It's common, to have both expressions and instructions combined.

```
GotoXY (Sum(Delta, W), B - Z);
```

So, you may have to transform the inner expressions and inner functions calls first.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are trying to convert infix notation to postfix, [Shunting-yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) might be what you are looking for.